# Hammer.js breaks vertical scroll when horizontal pan

Tags: scroll, touch, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js to look for horizontal pan gestures, I've devised a simple function to clicks a button when panned left or right. It works okay, except the vertical scroll doesn't do anything on a touch device, or it's really glitchy and weird.

Here's the function:

```
var panelSliderPan = function() {
    // Pan options
    myOptions = {
        // possible option
    };

    var myElement = document.querySelector('.scroll__inner'),
        mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
    mc.add(new Hammer.Pan(myOptions));

    // Pan control
    var panIt = function(e) {
        // I'm checking the direction here, my common sense says it shouldn't
        // affect the vertical gestures, but it blocks them somehow
        // 2 means it's left pan
        if (e.direction === 2) {
            $('.controls__btn--next').click();
        // 4 == right
        } else if (e.direction === 4) {
            $('.controls__btn--prev').click();
        }
    };

    // Call it
    mc.on("panstart", function(e) {
        panIt(e);
    });
};
```

I've tried to add a horizontal direction to the recognizer but it didn't really help (not sure if I did it even right):

```
mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, {
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Pan,{ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }],
    ]
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a working jsfiddle so we can help you.

Answer (score 11):

Try setting the [`touch-action` property](http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-action/) to `auto`.

```
mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, {
    touchAction: 'auto',
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Pan,{ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }],
    ]
});
```

From the hammer.js docs:

> When you set the touchAction to auto it doesnt prevent any defaults, and Hammer would probably break. You have to call preventDefault manually to fix this. You should only use this if you know what you're doing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The requirement to call preventDefault (or return false) seems very standard to prevent events' default behaviours (if that is what you want).

Comment: makes it scrollable again, but breaks the swipe gesture

Comment: So much of hammerjs documentation *almost* makes sense :-/ do you know what they really mean by this. I have this kind of gut instinct feeling that I understand this comment but I also really don’t!

Answer (score 2):

User patforna is correct. You need to adjust the `touch-action` property. This will fix scrolling not working when you have hammer bound on a big element in mobile.

You create a Hammer instance like so

```
var h = new Hammer(options.contentEl, {
    touchAction : 'auto'
});
```

I was working on a pull to refresh feature, so I need the `pan` event.

Add the recognizers.

```
h.get( 'pan' ).set({
    direction   : Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL,
});

h.on('panstart pandown panup panend', eventHandler);
```

Inside the eventhandler, you'd look at the event that was triggered and manually call on `event.preventDefault()` when you require it. This is applicable for hammer 2.0.6.

For anyone who's looking the pull to refresh code was taken from - https://github.com/apeatling/web-pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that vertical scroll was toggling a sidebar that was supposed to show/hide on horizontal pan/swipe. After looking at the event details, I realized that Hammer probably triggers panleft and panright event based on X delta and doesn't consider Y delta, so my quick solution was to check the pan direction in my handler:

```
this.$data.$hammer.on('panleft', (e) => {
    if (Math.abs(e.deltaY) > Math.abs(e.deltaX)) {
        return;
    }

    this.isVisible = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for several days. Hope this will fix your problem.

```
 mc = new Hammer(myElement, {
            inputClass: Hammer.SUPPORT_POINTER_EVENTS ? Hammer.PointerEventInput : Hammer.TouchInput,
            touchAction: 'auto',
        });
```

When the relevant gesture is triggered, we applied a css class to the element, that would set the touch-action to none.

```
 mc.on('panmove panstart', event => {
        mc.addClass('is-dragging');
    }
);
```

```
.is-dragging {
        touch-action: none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Hammer 2.x does not support vertical swipe/pan. [Documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/) says:

> *Notes:*
>   When calling Hammer() to create a simple instance, the pan and swipe recognizers are configured to **only detect horizontal gestures**

You can however use [older 1.1.x version](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/tree/1.1.x), which supports vertical gestures

——

Clarification: this refers to a ‘simple instance’ which is when you don’t pass in any recognizer configuration as the second parameter. In other words these are the defaults but can (and usually should) be overridden.

Comment: I wasn't looking vertical pan, but horizontal pan, which works. But it also disables normal vertical scrolling.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this, I am having a similar issue..?

Comment: This isn't true I believe.You just need to set `direction` to `Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL` when initializing the `pan` recognizer.

Comment: like @stradosphere Hammer 2 does support vertical panning, just use the DIRECTION_VERTICAL constant in your constructor.

Comment: @Juan - I am not using a constructor anywhere, just angular directive that binds a swipe event using hmTouchEvents module and hm-swiperight and hm-swipeleft directives.

Comment: @stradosphere see this pen: http://codepen.io/jtangelder/pen/ABFnd
It seems you are using a wrapper for angular, which can introduce other issues. But vanilla Hammer supports vertical panning perfectly well